# User Home relative path in a servlet init-parm

Tags: servlets

Can a path relative to user home be specified in a servlet init-parm?

I want to have the servlet load a property file from a path relative to the user running the server (likely tomcat).

Comment: I cannot change the servlet at the moment, maybe later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they can't by themselves.  However, I could see an init-param that:

1. Includes something like ${user.home}/filename.  In this case you'd have to parse the ${user.home} to do a System.getProperty() with the contents of the string between the curly brackets.
2. Is known to be a path relative to the user home directory.  So if the init-param is "/filename", your code will read the parameter and know that it has to prepend System.getProperty("user.home").

Either of these methods would be in the init() method of the servlet and either set a static variable in the servlet or interact with the property file there.